# What are the odds of 8 being drawn out of a group of 10 digits 5 times in 8 tries?

Tags: probability, odds

I am wanting to know the odds of something happening. What are the odds of 8 being drawn out of a group of 10 digits 5 times in 8 tries?

Comment: Which digits appear in this group??

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the ten digits are $0, 1, 2, \dots, 9,$ then on any one draw,
the probability of 'Success' (getting the `8`) is $p = 1/10.$
Then the probability of five successes in eight independent tries is
$P(X=5; n=8, p=1/10) = 0.000408$ is based on $X \sim\mathsf{Binom}(n=8,p=1/10):$

In R, where `dbinom` is a binomial PDF:

```
dbinom(5, 8, .1)
[1] 0.00040824
```

Using the binomial PDF formula, one could evaluate
${8\choose 5}(.1)^5(.9)^3 = 0.000408:$

```
choose(8,5)
[1] 56
56 * .1^5 * .9^3
[1] 0.00040824
```

With this interpretation of your question, I see no role here for
a hypergeometric distribution. If you have a different interpretation of the question, please edit it to clarify from among what digits `8`
is chosen and whether the repeated eight 'tries' are independent (taken from the same ten digits on each try).